# Error calling external accessor function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

If I have a class

```
Class A 
{
    public:
        UINT getfoo ();

... other stuff ...

    private:
        UINT initfoo (data);
        UINT foo;

     ... other stuff ...
}
```

The idea is, in the class constructor, I set

```
foo = initfoo (data);
```

getfoo is a simple return statment

```
UNIT getfoo ()
{
     return foo;
}
```

Then from an external function, where I have an instance of that class, I use the getfoo accessor function to get the value of foo in that class.

```
 A    a;
 UINT myfoo;
 ...
 myfoo = A::getfoo
 -or-
 myfoo = a.getfoo
```

But when I try to assign a the value of the same type in an external function, I keep getting an error.

Using A:: VS2013 gives me an error in the editor

> A value of type UINT (A::*)() cannot be assigned to an entity of type
>   UINT

Using a. the editor doesn’t complain, but when I try to compile I get the error:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'unsigned int (__thiscall
>   A::*)(void)' to 'unsigned int'

I'm sure this is a basic c++ issue, and I've searched a lot but I can't seem to find the right search terms to figure out my problem. What am I doing wrong in the function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function call should be this:

```
myfoo = a.getfoo();
```

Also, it is not normal for a mutator to return a value, so

```
UINT initfoo (data);
```

should probably be

```
void initfoo (data);
```

Also it is good practise to stick to the following naming conventions for accessors/mutators:

```
UINT foo;
UINT getFoo();
void setFoo(UINT val);
```

**EDIT** with const example:

```
class A
{
public:

  // Initialise foo to some random number
  A()
    : foo(4U)
  {
    // constructor body here
  }

private:
  // Once initialised foo cannot change during the lifetime of this object
  const UINT foo;
};
```

For clarity I've written the declarations and implementation together. If you split it into .h/.cpp, the intitialiser list goes in the .cpp with the constructor definition

Comment: Wow. Parentheses. I new it was something obvious. I feel stupid asking the question now, but thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: I didn't design initfoo to be a mutator. It simply returns an initial value for foo based on data. My constructor function initializes foo to the value from initfoo and never touches foo again. My understanding is mutators are typically used when called from an external function to try to change the value in the class. Once foo is set in the constructor, I don't want to modify it again, so I'm not using a mutator. Is my thinking wrong here?

Comment: No that sounds ok, but there might be a better way to achieve that. If you really don't want a class member to change, you can enforce that by making it 'const' and initialise it in the constructors initialiser list. I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: This pattern doesn't work for me. The issue is, "data" requires some code to execute to determine what should be in it, then this is passed to the initfoo function to determine the value of foo. Since declaring const requires it to be initialized immediately upon calling the constructor I cannot set it to the value it needs to be this way. That data may be different each time the code is run (it's hardware dependent), but then once it is initialized it is never changed.